# How to test if a kinit is needed?

Tags: bash, hadoop, kerberos

I would like to add something to my `.bashrc` file to run a `kinit` if I need one.  Is there a way to test if I need to do a `kinit`? Something like this:

```
if [ kinitNeeded ]; 
    do kinit; 
done

kinitNeeded() { ??? }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could try `klist -s`. From the man page:

"causes klist to run silently (produce no output), but to still set the exit status according to whether it finds the credentials cache.  The exit status is ‘0’ if klist finds a credentials cache, and ‘1’ if it does not or if the tickets are expired."

Comment: I just tried this and `echo $?` gives an exit status of 2.

Comment: @anthonybell [seems to work for me](https://gist.github.com/tellisnz/76f2dbcad7f7330eb2961781dbca79d8)

Comment: @anthonybell your solution doesn't account for expired tickets.. you could do something like `klist -s | echo $? -gt 0`

Comment: I am getting an error when I run `kinit -s`: `kinit: option requires an argument -- 's'`

Comment: @anthonybell what is your os and klist version etc?

Comment: Thanks, this solution works.  I was using `kinit -s` instead of `klist -s`

Comment: `if ! klist -s; then ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
klist -s; echo $?
```

Return `0` if is OK, `1` otherwise

Comment: Your answer doesn't bring anything new/useful regarding other existing answers. I suggest you to delete it.

Comment: I wrote this comment after solving the same problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but it's a bit of a hack.

```
if [ `klist 2>&1 | grep -i 'No credentials' | wc -l` -gt 0 ]; then
    kinit
fi
```

Comment: This doesn't address the situation when ticket is expired. @tellisnz's answer does.